# Binding Webgrid in MVC with Custom class in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

Hello I am new to AngularJS, I want to bind the webgrid in then method of AngularJS

```
$scope.SaveDetails = function () {
                debugger;
                var UserID = '@Session["ID"]';
                var ID ={ "Application_ID": $scope.Application.ID, "Release_ID": $scope.Release.ID, "Change_ID": $scope.Change.ID, "Environment_ID": $scope.Environment.ID, "Server_ID": $scope.Server.ID, "User_ID": UserID };


                if ($scope.Application || $scope.Release || $scope.Change || $scope.Environment || $scope.Server)
                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: '/Dashboard/SaveDetails/',
                        data: { Application_ID: $scope.Application.ID, Release_ID: $scope.Release.ID, Change_ID: $scope.Change.ID, Environment_ID: $scope.Environment.ID, Server_ID: $scope.Server.ID, User_ID: UserID },
                    }).then(function (resposne) {
                        debugger;
                        $scope.grid = resposne.data;
                        alert("Saved Successfully");
                    });
            }
```

I want to bind the webgrid before alert message. The data coming from the server is in the form of custom class

```
[HttpPost]
        public List<LogData> SaveDetails(SelectedID x)
        {
            application.SaveLogs(x.Application_ID, x.Release_ID, x.Change_ID, x.Environment_ID, x.Server_ID, x.User_ID);
            BLLogTable logs = new BLLogTable();
            List<LogData> data = new List<LogData>();
            data = logs.GetData(10, 10);
            return data;
        }
```

This is my Business layer.

```
public class BLLogTable
{
    BRMContext db = new BRMContext();

    public List<LogData> GetData(int rowCount, int rowFrom)
    {
        var param1 = new SqlParameter();
        param1.ParameterName = "@Value1";
        param1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
        param1.SqlValue = rowCount;

        var param2 = new SqlParameter();
        param2.ParameterName = "@Value2";
        param2.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
        param2.SqlValue = rowFrom;

        var query = db.LogDataContext.SqlQuery("BRM.spLogs @value1,@value2", param1, param2).ToList();
        List<LogData> x = new List<LogData>();

        foreach (var log in query)
            x.Add(log);

        return x;
    }

}
```

I saw many answers using ajax calls. But I was unsure if they would work. I followed this answer [MVC 3 Razor- how to bind new model to webgrid using jQuery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397837/mvc-3-razor-how-to-bind-new-model-to-webgrid-using-jquery-ajax)

I am able to get the data in the angularjs function [The data is in custom class object LogsData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4VyO.png.). How can I bind that data in mvc webgrid?

Little Help Would be really great! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am confused as to what is your issue.  You said you are able to get the data...is not displaying in the grid?

Comment: Yes, I have a mvc webgrid in the view. My doubt is how to bind the response data to that webgrid.

Comment: I'm looking at information on webgrid and I don't see how it would work with Angular.  You could try using Angular ui-grid here http://ui-grid.info/ or Kendo has a grid that works with Angular.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Rani Radcliff the alternative helped. I got the idea of the solution from there.

Comment: Good deal.  I often get ideas from other solutions.  I'm glad I was able to help a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using Partial view and rendered the webgrid in it. I called the partial view in the document load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.get("@Url.Action("RefreshGrid", "Dashboard")", function (data) {
            $('#divProduct').replaceWith(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

and just called the button click event using in angular to render the partial view again.

Answer (score 0):

The rendering of the grid should occur before the button click. If the sequence is not maintained the grid wont show up.